# Java ArrayList possible to delete everything except given key?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I have an ArrayList *ArrayListA* consists of 4 objects *basketball*,*football*,*rugby*,*badminton*.

Is there a method where it will return *ArrayListA* with only the specific object? By specifying *basketball*， this method will delete everything in *ArrayListA* that isn't *basketball* ?

**Update:**

By clearing the ArrayList and add the object manually doesn't fit what I want. *ArrayListA* expected to be empty if *basketball* not found.

Comment: `list.removeIf(s -> !s.getName().equals("basketball"));` - or whatever suits your objects.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way to do this is:

```
list.clear();
list.add(yourObject);
```

**UPDATE:**

So if you want to check the existence, for you can do `list.indexOf`

```
      boolean found = false;
      if(list.indexOf(yourObject) != -1){
          found =true;
      }
      list.clear();
      if(found){
          list.add(yourObject);
      }
```

Comment: @karthik: Please help refer to my latest update. Sorry for the lack of information

Comment: What if the list contains multiple items equals to yourObject?

Comment: @SergeyGazaryan OP would have mentioned it, If that was a real concern for him.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing specifically for that in the JDK, but you can use [`ArrayList#removeIf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) passing it a predicate that matches everything except the entry you want to keep.

Or of course [`List#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) to get the index of the entry, then remove all other entries (first the ones after it, then the ones before) via [`removeRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange-int-int-).

Or, since you already have the one you want to keep, remove everything and add it back.